# Spring Boot Test initializing static constants inside a component

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, static, resources

I have a component `Constants` which contains some static fields/constants which get initialized when the component is created. All values are loaded from *src\main\resources\application.yml* . The problem with this is that when I call it inside a test method, fields are not initialized

```
@Component
public class Constants {

    public static String XXX;    

    @Value("${userRegistry.XXX}")
    public void setXXX(String xxx) {
        XXX= xxx;
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Swagger2SpringBoot.class })
public class SearchUserTest {


    @Test
    public void searchUserById() {

        System.out.println("TEST: "+Constants.XXX);  <-- null

    }
}
```

Swagger2Spring:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.microservice.userRegistry")
public class Swagger2SpringBoot implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        if (arg0.length > 0 && arg0[0].equals("exitcode")) {
            throw new ExitException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication(Swagger2SpringBoot.class).run(args);
    }

    class ExitException extends RuntimeException implements ExitCodeGenerator {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public int getExitCode() {
            return 10;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a src\ **test** \resources\application.yml.  Why are those attributes static?

Comment: @AndrewS sorry Im new on spring, where to add that

Comment: Same path, just under the test folder structure.

Comment: @AndrewS are static because are used as constants

Comment: @AndrewS didn't worked, I replicated src/main/resources files under src/test/resources

Comment: Why the @PrepareForTest?  Is that attempting to mock the class?  Not sure why that would be needed.

Comment: @AndrewS no sorry, my mistake, it's not needed. Howerver it does't work eaven if I remove it

Comment: Swagger2SpringBoot does a component scan?

Comment: @AndrewS yes, it does

Comment: Sorry - not sure what else to suggest!